# Unwanted double quotes in json

Tags: .net, json

I have the following code in .NET

```
public JsonResult<string> Get()
    {
        Message message1 = new Message("lala1");
        Message message2 = new Message("lala2");

        List<Message> listOfMessages = new List<Message>();

        listOfMessages.Add(message1);
        listOfMessages.Add(message2);

        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(listOfMessages);
        return Json(json);
    }
```

What I get as a result is:

"[{\"message\":\"lala1\"},{\"message\":\"lala2\"}]"

I do not want the double quotes (`""`) in the start and in the end. Why does it add them ?

Comment: I think double-quoting fields in json field names is part of the JSON format, and the tools displaying it without showing them (e.g. JSON view extension) do this for readability purposes. Take a tool like http://json2csharp.com/, you will see it won't accept JSON without double-quoted field names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN documentation for `JavaScriptSerializer` class actually [recommends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) the following:

> Json.NET should be used [for] serialization and deserialization.

JSON.NET library became de-facto standard for working with JSON in .NET, for example, it is a default serializer that is used with ASP.NET Web API ([link](https://www.infoq.com/news/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-4-rc/)).

Here is how you can re-write your code to use JSON.NET (be sure to add Newtonsoft.Json nuget package to your solution):

```
public static void Main()
{
    var result = SerializeMessages();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public static string SerializeMessages()
{
    var listOfMessages = new List<Message>
    {
        new Message("lala1"),
        new Message("lala2")
    };

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listOfMessages);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to serialize JSON in JSON.
Change :

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(listOfMessages);
return Json(json);
```

to :

```
return Json(listOfMessages);
```

Comment: To merge with @oldbam, the Json() method is exposed by every MVC controller, and uses the default serializer, which is actually JSON.Net in latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using and returning a List Of JObjects.